# How to print threadid instead of threadname by using NLog when .Net Thread does not have name?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, logging, nlog

I have NLog configuration like below.

It prints name of thread if it exists. Otherwise I get empty string instead of thread name.

**Question:** how can I archive behavior below?

- If thread has name - print name of thread
- Otherwise - print ManagedThreadId (e.g. the same with `threadid` NLog variable).

Current configuration example:

```xml
<variable name="defaultLayout" value="${date} ${level} [${threadname}] ${logger} - ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}"/>

<targets async="true">
  <target name="ConsoleAppender" 
          type="ColoredConsole" 
          layout="${var:defaultLayout}" />
</targets>
```

Please note: I'd like to avoid printing both variables, e.g. this layout of not useful: `... [${threadname}-${threadid}] ...`

Comment: If you could live with having both thread ID and thread name (if there is any) logged together, you could simply define your own layout... (https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers)

Comment: @elgonzo, I agree. However I'd like to write only one variable from above. Will note this in question, thank you.

Comment: FYI: If you really want to output thread ID only if no thread name is present, make sure you cannot confuse the two in your log. After all, some thread could be named "123" while another (unnamed) thread could have the thread ID 123...

Comment: I am not sure, but it could perhaps be possible to use one of the conditional layout renderers ${When} or ${WhenEmpty}...

Comment: @elgonzo, yes of course. The most of our threads have pretty names like "XXX Object Loader" or "YYY Data Publisher". And we'd like to have these names in logs and avoid adding thread identity. And you are right, in this case thread with id 123 will be printed in the same way with thread with name "123". Regarding to ${WhenEmpty} - agree, will check and publish results.

Comment: @elgonzo, you was absolutely right. This worked: ${threadname:whenEmpty=${threadid}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR: use this - `${threadname:whenEmpty=${threadid}}`

So right configuration:

```xml
<variable name="defaultLayout" value="${date} ${level} [${threadname:whenEmpty=${threadid}}] ${logger} - ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}"/>

<targets async="true">
   <target name="ConsoleAppender" 
      type="ColoredConsole" 
      layout="${var:defaultLayout}" />
</targets>
```